# Recupera información en fecha y hora especifica de Google Finance

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

He estado trabajando con la función de google "***GOOGLE FINANCE***" en las **hojas de calculo de google** para obtener información bursátil. 
He leído la documentación (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=es) y algunos ejemplos, pero lo que necesito es realizar una consulta que me traiga el precio de cualquier activo (**preferible CURRENCIES, como EURUSD**) en una fecha y hora en especifico, por ejemplo cual fue el precio de cotización de EURUSD hoy 1 de octubre a las 9:30

Cual seria la consulta correcta?,
Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

## Respuesta corta

No se puede

## Explicación

Como puedes ver en el artículo de ayuda referido, la sintaxis de GOOGLEFINANCE() no incluye la consulta de horas específicas